# Entity Framework- SaveChanges: save some changes if some other fails

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have following code which adds a list of `EntityX` and then calls `SaveChanges`.

For some items in `EntityX`, there might be a primary key violation and thus it fails.

I still want Entity Framework to go ahead and save the rest of the items from the list, even though some of them failed.

```
await dbContext.EntityX.AddRangeAsync(data);
await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: You can't, EF will save all or nothing. Filter data before passing to ChangeTracker.

Comment: You can save them one by one

Answer (score 0):

Without saving entities one by one, assuming your EntityX has **Id** primary key, I would write:

```
List<int> allIds = dbContext.EntityX.Select(c => c.Id).ToList();
List<EntityX> data2 = data.Where(c => allIds.IndexOf(c.Id) == -1).ToList();
await dbContext.EntityX.AddRangeAsync(data2);
await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

I put in data2 the entities to save that doesn't have an already existing Id.